# Latest WINE update broke Levelator (can't start it now), what can be done about it?

Tags: wine

I have been running Conversation Network's Levelator for a couple of years without problem.  With the latest Wine (1.3.28) it won't start. It gives me the **Encountered a serious problem** dialog and in the terminal shows

```
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000400 at address 0x68486a63 (thread 0009)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, is there anything I can set, can I easily roll back to a previous wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [winetricks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/winetricks) [image: Install winetricks].

- Run `winetricks`.
- Choose to install a library (DLL).
- Install windows common controls version 6.
- Try running the program again.

If that does not work, undo the operation (with `winetricks` again; if it supports it).

You can try to install the application with [playonlinux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/playonlinux) [image: Install playonlinux]. This would allow you to choose a WINE version that works, and not have to downgrade your local WINE installation.

Comment: The only common controls that show up in my version (I did a wget of winetricks just now) is "MS Common controls 5.8 which is installed. Or there is a MS RichTextBox control 6 that is also installed. Is there a winetricks command line for what you are explaining?  On the other hand I filed a bug and though I'm new to the process it looks like it was confirmed and there may be a patch coming. http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28441

Comment: @Dennis: congrats on filing a bug. It is better for the problem to be fixed within WINE. Have you tried POL?

Comment: re: POL Not yet, I only use 2 windows programs and since I don't really understand how multiple WINE installations would work especially if for example I do a dist-upgrade I hate to get things to far from the standard. Since both programs were working I'm not even positive I should have been updating. All I do is process 1 audio file per week (and use Notepad++ for some HTML edits).

Comment: @Dennis: POL will keep your WINE applications in a kind of sandbox, so I highly suggest it, especially for someone who does not know how WINE works.

Comment: However I'm open to compelling reasons to spend some time learning it if there are. Or input on how things work during upgrades and such given my use case. (We posted at the same time), I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I went with POL, and though the bug now show as fixed and I assume it would work the next time WINE updates, it was worth seeing how easy it was to add an older version of WINE and install an "unsupported" app which just seems to mean there isn't a profile created in the default POL install.  Works great, thanks !!

Comment: There is no windows common controls version 6 in winetricks.